# Writing an HTTP query with Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

Can I use the Tornado facilities to write HTTP client queries?  As opposed to using the  http.client module in the standard library.

What would be the equivalent Tornado code for:

```
curl 'http://localhost:2222/foo?bar=1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal equivalent is

```
python -m tornado.httpclient 'http://localhost:2222/foo?bar=1'
```

Or in a coroutine

```
print (yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch('http://localhost:2222/foo?bar=1')).body
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! It's the second I'll actually be using, but the first is very interesting to know about.